# MS Access - Get the current query name of a subform

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a classic form and a subform that obtain records from a query
and i want to assign to a variable the name of that query used by the subform:

```
Dim qryVar as String
qryVar = Me.subForm1.Query.Name
```

this doesn't work of course..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the parent form's code

```
Sub Test()
    Dim qryVar as string
    qryVar = Me.Controls("SubForm1").Form.RecordSource
    debug.print qryVar
End Sub
```

In Module code to call the test

```
Sub TestFormCode()
     Frm_ParentFormObject.Test 'Change this to whatever your form's name is
End Sub
```

Comment: RecordSource returns all the SQL code, i need just the name of the query used. For query i mean the query name displayed on the left side list.

Comment: It shouldn't be, unless that is a change and you are using a different version than I am. If you go to properties of the subform is it a sql string or an actual query?

Comment: For query i mean the query name displayed on the left side list.

Comment: the properties of the subform has no sql and no query.. is blank

Comment: You have no recordsource in the data tab of the properties sheet in the design view of the subform?

Comment: yes.. because i leave it blank for VBA coding onLoad

Comment: even if it will be a resourcecode, it will returns all the SQL lines.. i need just the query name used by the form

Comment: Are you using a query in the code or passing SQL? You might need to take the name of the query from the onload and pass it as a parameter or set it to a global if the calls aren't consecutive.

Comment: i'm passing a SQL to it

Comment: Then there is no query name because you are creating one on the fly... If you make a query and use that query's code you will have a query name.

Comment: you are right.. just tried with a normal form with SQL and returns the query name.. thanks